# Android: mhandler.postDelayed() not accurate when screen off

Tags: android

I am using mhandler.postDelayed(runnable,5000) to write data to a file for every 5 seconds.

When the screen is off, I observed from the file the timing for the postDelayed(runnable,5000).
It is accurate for sometime but after for one hour, the timing for postDelayed(runnable,5000) increase to 10secs.

After two hour, the timing for postDelayed(runnable,5000) increase to 15secs.
After three hour, the timing for postDelayed(runnable,5000) increase to 20secs and so on..

It seems very strange that the postDelayed trigger timing changes with time.

Am I expecting this or there is a error in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use something else than a Handler.

Try a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) :

```
int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        //...Perform a task...
    }
};
new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

Comment: Is Timer a good method? I will try it. If it still cannot works, I may use AlarmManager instead.

Comment: Yeah it should, I used it one time to create a countdown.